# The Method ScrollTo has no use

Tags: android, scroll

I made a android program to read books.. And I want to make it possible to open a tag ,and when you open a tag, the program will open the book and scroll to the position which is told in the tag .

But in my app,the ScrollTo function seems no reaction .

Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reader);

        scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Scroll);
        text       = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tagsButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Tags);
        openButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Open);

        text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        text.scrollTo(0, index);
    }//Here the scrollTo do not work...
```

The process in onCreate is not important ,so I delete them..

What is puzzling me is that in the method below the method scroll can work...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(data!=null){
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null){
        int index = bundle.getInt("Index");
        String file_name = bundle.getString("File_Name");


        ReadFile(file_name);
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, index);
        text.postInvalidate();
        }
        }
```

I don't think there's so much difference between these two methods...But why...

Anyone can help me?

THX a lot.

Answer (score 7):

in your onCreate try

```
 text.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            text.scrollTo(...);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now...  I thought no one can understand my meaning because of my poor English...

Comment: it's something like the view is not fully inflated/initialized in the onCreate. The post method queues this code in the messageQueue for the textView, and thus you are sure it is initialized there. If this works for you, can you approve the answer?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  I would have never thought of this on my own.